# Can we solve the Dirichlet problem for Laplace equation under weaker assumptions?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

We consider the Dirichlet-problem for the Laplace equation
\begin{align}
-\Delta u=0~~\mbox{in } \Omega, u=g \mbox{ in } \partial \Omega 
\end{align}
where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $n\geq 2$, is a bounded domain and $g \in \mathcal{C}^0(\partial\Omega)$. We search for classical solutions, i.e. $u \in \mathcal{C}^2(\Omega)\cap \mathcal{C}^0(\overline{\Omega})$.

The Perron method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron_method) gives us a solution if $\partial \Omega$ is Dirichlet regular, i.e. for each $\xi \in \partial \Omega$ there exists a barrier $b \in \mathcal{C}^0(\overline{\Omega})$, that is, $b$ is superharmonic in $\Omega$ and $b(x_0)=0$ and $b>0$ in $\overline{\Omega}\setminus \{\xi\}$.

My question is whether this assumption can be weakened.

Comment: Yes, but not much. See Armitage and Gardiner.